# How to delete rows using an outer join

Tags: postgresql, left-join, using

I've got a problem to delete records from a PostgreSQL table, using a `LEFT JOIN`.

I'd like to delete rows I get with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM url 
LEFT JOIN link_type ON url.link_type = link_type.id 
WHERE link_type.id IS NULL
```

To do so, here is what I did:

```
 DELETE FROM url
 USING link_type
 WHERE url.link_type = link_type.id  AND link_type.id IS NULL
```

Query works but doesn't delete anything, although that's exactly what's explained in the doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html.

Is my problem due to `IS NULL` in the query or Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't delete anything because when `link_type.id` is null, `url.link_type = link_type.id` is not true so these two conditions are never satisfied together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Still don't understand why my previous query doesn't work (if someone could explain, would be nice), but here is how I did the trick:

```
DELETE FROM url WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM link_type WHERE url.link_type = link_type.id );
```

Comment: Because if "url.link_type = link_type.id" is "TRUE" then "link_type.id" _is not "NULL"_, if "link_type.id" is "NULL" the first condition "url.link_type = link_type.id" will returns "NULL" too then you get "NULL AND TRUE" that is just "NULL". Since NULL is a unknow value you cannot say that it is TRUE or FALSE, so no rows is displayed. The NOT EXISTS will to the work for you.

Answer (score 13):

Good work, sun. Minor suggestion: when using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS you don't need to `SELECT *`. A common convention ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)) is to just write `SELECT 1` as like this:

```
DELETE FROM url WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM link_type WHERE url.link_type = link_type.id 
);
```

Functionally, both ways work.

Comment: I tried this query on two tables with 300k, and 600k rows respectively, and the query timed out after 30 minutes.