# Optimize Postgres deletion of orphaned records

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Take the following two tables:

```sql
Table "public.contacts"
       Column       |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('contacts_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              |
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              |
 external_id        | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              |
 email_address      | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 first_name         | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 last_name          | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 company            | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 industry           | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 country            | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 region             | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
 ext_instance_id    | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              |
 title              | character varying           |                                                       | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "contacts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_contacts_on_ext_instance_id_and_external_id" UNIQUE, btree (ext_instance_id, external_id)
```

and

```
Table "public.members"
        Column         |            Type             |                             Modifiers                              | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer                     | not null default nextval('members_id_seq'::regclass)               | plain    |              |
 step_id               | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 contact_id            | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 rule_id               | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 request_id            | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 sync_id               | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 status                | integer                     | not null default 0                                                 | plain    |              |
 matched_targeted_rule | boolean                     | default false                                                      | plain    |              |
 external_fields       | jsonb                       |                                                                    | extended |              |
 imported_at           | timestamp without time zone |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 campaign_id           | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 ext_instance_id       | integer                     |                                                                    | plain    |              |
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone |                                                                    | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "members_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_members_on_contact_id_and_step_id" UNIQUE, btree (contact_id, step_id)
    "index_members_on_campaign_id" btree (campaign_id)
    "index_members_on_step_id" btree (step_id)
    "index_members_on_sync_id" btree (sync_id)
    "index_members_on_request_id" btree (request_id)
    "index_members_on_status" btree (status)
```

Indices exist for both primary keys and `members.contact_id`.

I need to delete any `contact` which has no related `members`. There are roughly 3MM `contact` and 25MM `member` records.

I'm attempting the following two queries:

### Query 1:

```
DELETE FROM "contacts"
WHERE  "contacts"."id" IN (SELECT "contacts"."id" 
                           FROM   "contacts" 
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN members 
                                               ON 
                                  members.contact_id = contacts.id 
                           WHERE  members.id IS NULL);

DELETE 0
Time: 173033.801 ms

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on contacts  (cost=2654306.79..2654307.86 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=188717.354..188717.354 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2654306.79..2654307.86 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=188717.351..188717.351 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2654306.36..2654306.37 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=188717.349..188717.349 rows=0 loops=1)
               Group Key: contacts_1.id
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=161177.46..2654306.36 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=188717.345..188717.345 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (members.contact_id = contacts_1.id)
                     Filter: (members.id IS NULL)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 26725870
                     ->  Seq Scan on members  (cost=0.00..1818698.96 rows=25322396 width=14) (actual time=0.043..160226.686 rows=26725870 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=105460.65..105460.65 rows=3205265 width=10) (actual time=1962.612..1962.612 rows=3196180 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 262144  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 34361kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on contacts contacts_1  (cost=0.00..105460.65 rows=3205265 width=10) (actual time=0.011..950.657 rows=3196180 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using contacts_pkey on contacts  (cost=0.43..1.48 rows=1 width=10) (never executed)
               Index Cond: (id = contacts_1.id)
 Planning time: 0.488 ms
 Execution time: 188718.862 ms
```

### Query 2:

```
DELETE FROM contacts 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   members c 
                   WHERE  c.contact_id = contacts.id); 

DELETE 0
Time: 170871.219 ms

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on contacts  (cost=2258873.91..2954594.50 rows=1895601 width=12) (actual time=177523.034..177523.034 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=2258873.91..2954594.50 rows=1895601 width=12) (actual time=177523.029..177523.029 rows=0 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (contacts.id = c.contact_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on contacts  (cost=0.00..105460.65 rows=3205265 width=10) (actual time=0.018..1068.357 rows=3196180 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1818698.96..1818698.96 rows=25322396 width=10) (actual time=169587.802..169587.802 rows=26725870 loops=1)
               Buckets: 262144  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 36228kB
               ->  Seq Scan on members c  (cost=0.00..1818698.96 rows=25322396 width=10) (actual time=0.052..160081.880 rows=26725870 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.901 ms
 Execution time: 177524.526 ms
```

As you can see that without even deleting any records both queries show similar performance taking ~3 minutes.

The server disk I/O spikes to 100% so I'm assuming that data is being spilled out to the disk because a sequential scan is done on both `contacts` and `members`.

The server is an EC2 r3.large (15GB RAM).

Any ideas on what I can do to optimize this query?

### Update #1:

After running `vacuum analyze` for both tables and ensuring `enable_mergejoin` is set to `on` there is no difference in the query time:

```
DELETE FROM contacts 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   members c 
                   WHERE  c.contact_id = contacts.id); 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on contacts  (cost=2246088.17..2966677.08 rows=1875003 width=12) (actual time=209406.342..209406.342 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=2246088.17..2966677.08 rows=1875003 width=12) (actual time=209406.338..209406.338 rows=0 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (contacts.id = c.contact_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on contacts  (cost=0.00..105683.28 rows=3227528 width=10) (actual time=0.008..1010.643 rows=3227462 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1814029.74..1814029.74 rows=24855474 width=10) (actual time=198054.302..198054.302 rows=27307060 loops=1)
               Buckets: 262144  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 37006kB
               ->  Seq Scan on members c  (cost=0.00..1814029.74 rows=24855474 width=10) (actual time=1.132..188654.555 rows=27307060 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.328 ms
 Execution time: 209408.040 ms
```

### Update 2:

PG Version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (Gentoo Hardened 4.5.4 p1.0, pie-0.4.7) 4.5.4, 64-bit
```

Relation size:

```
         Table         |  Size   | External Size
-----------------------+---------+---------------
 members               | 23 GB   | 11 GB
 contacts              | 944 MB  | 371 MB
```

Settings:

```
 work_mem
----------
 64MB

 random_page_cost
------------------
 4
```

### Update 3:

Experimenting with doing this in batches doesn't seem to help out on the I/O usage (still spikes to 100%) and doesn't seem to improve on time despite using index-based plans.

```
DO $do$ 
BEGIN 
  FOR i IN 57..668 
  LOOP 
    DELETE 
    FROM   contacts 
    WHERE  contacts.id IN 
           ( 
                           SELECT          contacts.id 
                           FROM            contacts 
                           left outer join members 
                           ON              members.contact_id = contacts.id 
                           WHERE           members.id IS NULL 
                           AND             contacts.id >= (i    * 10000) 
                           AND             contacts.id < ((i+1) * 10000));
END LOOP;END $do$;
```

I had to kill the query after `Time: 1203492.326 ms` and disk I/O stayed at 100% the entire time the query ran. I also experimented with 1,000 and 5,000 chunks but did not see any increase in performance.

Note: The `57..668` range was used because I know those are existing contact IDs. (E.g. `min(id)` and `max(id)`)

Comment: Gut feeling: your work_mem is set too *high*, and random_page_cost too high, and maybe the statistics are out of date or absent. BTW table definition should have been : `... contact_id integer references contact(id)` PLUS: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, please ...

Comment: Question updated. As far as foreign key constraints, this is in the context of a Rails app that doesn't automatically add them. However, I'm under the impression that foreign key constraints are only used to maintain referential integrity. Are you suggesting that they can be used to improve query performance?

Comment: Is there an index on members.contact_id?
Also: use "*" instead of "1" in query 2. It's the recommended practice in postgresql.

Comment: There is an index on `members.contact_id` (it's a compound index with another field and is unique.) Noted about the "*" - does that have any affect on query performance though?

Comment: if `members.contact_id` is the first member in the composite index, it will be usable. BTW in psql you can use `\d members` to show the current table structure. Maybe even add a `+`

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that the `contact_id` is the first field in the composite index.

Comment: I doubt those are your *actual* table definitions, which are *essential* to the question. *All* data types, constraints and indexes may be relevant. Total relation size is relevant. Settings are relevant, in particular `work_mem` and `random_page_cost`. Consider instructions in the tag info of [\[postgresql-performance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). How many rows (rough percentage) are deleted? Can you afford to lock the table exclusively for the operation?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Thanks for your reply. I've updated the question with real table definitions as well as the relation sizes and settings you asked about. In my testing of the queries it seems no rows are actually deleted - the time is spent on simply finding possible orphaned contacts. I can not lock the table for this operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas on what I can do to optimize this query?

Your queries are perfect. I would use the `NOT EXISTS` variant.
Your index `index_members_on_contact_id_and_step_id` is also good for it:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

But see below about BRIN indexes.

You can tune your server, table and index configuration.

Since you hardly update or delete any rows, according to your comment, focus on optimizing *read* performance.

#### 1. Upgrade your Postgres version

You provided:

> The server is an EC2 r3.large (15GB RAM).

And:

> PostgreSQL 9.4.4

Your version is seriously outdated. ***At least*** upgrade to the latest minor version. Better yet, upgrade to the current major version. Postgres 9.5 and 9.6 brought major improvements for big data - which is what you need exactly.

[Consider the versioning policy of the project.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

[Amazon allows you to upgrade!](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html)

#### 2. Improve table statistics

There is an unexpected 10% mismatch between expected and actual row count in the basic sequential scan:

> Seq Scan on members c  (cost=0.00..1814029.74 **rows=24855474** width=10) (actual time=1.132..188654.555 **rows=27307060** loops=1)

Not dramatic at all, but still should not occur in this query. Indicates that you might have to tune your `autovacuum` settings - possibly per table for the very big ones.

More problematic:

> Hash Anti Join  (cost=2246088.17..2966677.08 **rows=1875003** width=12) (actual time=209406.338..209406.338 **rows=0** loops=1)

Postgres expects to find 1875003 rows to delete, while actually 0 rows are found. That's unexpected. Maybe substantially increasing the statistics target on `members.contact_id` and `contacts.id` can help to decrease the gap, which might allow better query plans. See:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

#### 3. Avoid table and index bloat

Your ~ 25MM rows in `members` occupy 23 GB - that's almost 1kb per row, which seems excessive for the table definition you presented (even if the total size you provided should include indexes):

```
 4 bytes  item identifier

24        tuple header
 8        null bitmap
36        9x integer
16        2x ts
 1        1x bool
??        1x jsonb
```

See:

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570613/making-sense-of-postgres-row-sizes/13570853#13570853)

That's 89 bytes per row - or less with some NULL values - and hardly any alignment padding, so **96 bytes max**, plus your **`jsonb`** column.

**Either** that `jsonb` column is very big which would make me suggest to normalize the data into separate columns or a separate table. Consider:

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb/26704636#26704636)

**Or** your table is bloated, which can be solved with `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` or, while being at it:

```
CLUSTER members USING index_members_on_contact_id_and_step_id;
VACUUM members;
```

But either takes an exclusive lock on the table, which you say you cannot afford. [**`pg_repack`**](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) can do it without exclusive lock. See:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37032/3684)

Even if we factor in index sizes, your table seems too big: you have 7 small indexes, each 36 - 44 bytes per row without bloat, less with NULL values, so < 300 bytes altogether.

Either way, consider [more aggressive `autovacuum` settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) for your table `members`. Related:

- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21649/3684)
- [What fillfactor for caching table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36443/3684)

And / or stop bloating the table to begin with. Are you updating rows a lot? Any particular column you update a lot? That `jsonb` column maybe? You might move that to a separate (1:1) table just to stop bloating the main table with dead tuples - and keeping `autovacuum` from doing its job.

#### 4. Try a BRIN index

[Block range indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/brin.html) require Postgres **9.5 or later** and *dramatically* reduce index size. I was too optimistic in my first draft. A BRIN index is *perfect* for your use case if you have *many* rows in `members` for each `contact.id` - after **physically clustering** your table at least once (see ③ for the fitting `CLUSTER` command). In that case Postgres can rule out whole data pages quickly. But your numbers indicate only around 8 rows per `contact.id`, so data pages would often contain multiple values, which voids much of the effect. Depends on actual details of your data distribution ...

On the other hand, as it stands, your tuple size is around 1 kb, so only ~ 8 rows per data page (typically 8kb). If that isn't mostly bloat, a BRIN index might help after all.

But you need to upgrade your server version first. See ①.

```
CREATE INDEX members_contact_id_brin_idx ON members USING BRIN (contact_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for the wealth of information here. Upgrading is on my list but will take some time. In the meantime, I have clustered the table with the index you suggested but this did not reduce time/disk usage.  For the `members` table only the `status` and some of the `_id` columns get updated. The other columns (including the jsonb) only get populated on the insert once and then are used for queries.If I move that to a separate 1-1 table - wouldn't I have to go through that table as well and delete rows when corresponding `members` are deleted? I'm afraid it would cause more overhead.

Comment: In your opinion, should I focus on upgrading first or attempt to tune my current server? What do you think would have the greatest benefit? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1032752: If your table is bloated, I would clean that up first. And add more aggressive autovacuum setting for the table. Then upgrade to the latest Postgres version, which has various benefits. Then try to optimize some more. It depends on your whole situation.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to problems like this can be to do it in smaller chunks.

```
DELETE FROM "contacts"
WHERE  "contacts"."id" IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM contacts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN members ON members.contact_id = contacts.id 
    WHERE members.id IS NULL
        AND id >= 1 AND id < 1000
);
DELETE FROM "contacts"
WHERE  "contacts"."id" IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM contacts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN members ON members.contact_id = contacts.id 
    WHERE members.id IS NULL
        AND id >= 1001 AND id < 2000
);
```

Rinse, repeat.  Experiment with different chunk sizes to find an optimal one for your data set, which uses the fewest queries, while keeping them all in memory.

Naturally, you would want to script this, possibly in plpgsql, or in whatever scripting language you prefer.

Comment: I would wrap this in a pgplsql block after finding the appropriated chunk size to loop and commit after each chunk. +1 for the idea

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Yes, of course! It ought to be automated. It's worth mentioning that explicitly in the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping to avoid batching these but if that's going to reduce resource usage - I'll give it a shot. Please give me a bit to write up a script that I can test out against my production DB and I'll report back on the timing.

Comment: I've updated my question with the results of batching the query. Doesn't seem to improve time nor disk IO. I'm assuming this can help with maintaining a constant memory profile but not so much with needing to read both tables from the disk. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding or doing something wrong in my query. Thanks! (Just realized, I specifically said I need less memory consumption in my question - I guess that's related but not exactly accurate. I'm looking to reduce the disk IO when running this. Sorry for the confusion there.)

Comment: @user1032752: If your IDs are sequential, without gaps, you may improve performance by including a `LIMIT 10000`. This would tell the query it can stop the table scan (for the subquery) once 10000 rows are fetched.  If you have gaps, then you may never hit that limit without rewriting your subquery further.

Answer (score 1):

Update statistics used by the planner and set `enable_mergejoin` to `on`:

```
vacuum analyse members;
vacuum analyse contacts;
set enable_mergejoin to on;
```

You should get a query plan similar to this one:

```
explain analyse
delete from contacts 
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from members c 
    where c.contact_id = contacts.id); 

                               QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on contacts
   ->  Merge Anti Join
         Merge Cond: (contacts.id = c.contact_id)
         ->  Index Scan using contacts_pkey on contacts
         ->  Index Scan using members_contact_id_idx on members c
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my question with the query plan but unfortunately it did not help with the query time.

Comment: It's rather strange your server doesn't use indexes. The obvious cause would be if the parameter `enable_mergejoin` isn't set. Another possiblity would be setting `enable_indexscan` to off, but another plan in your question suggest it's on.
I've tested the query on three servers (with different Postgres versions) on 1M/2M data, all of them give the plan like in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Server is 9.4. I'm assuming it's something about the relation size that's causing the different plans.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant to try:

```
DELETE FROM contacts
USING contacts c
LEFT JOIN members m
ON c.id = m.contact_id
WHERE m.contact_id IS NULL;
```

It uses a technique for deleting from a joined query described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662726/delete-using-left-outer-join-in-postgres#33723604).

I can't vouch for whether this would definitely be faster but it might be because of the avoidance of a subquery. Would be interested in the results...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Not sure why but the query above ended up taking over 30 min and I had to kill it. It ran fine in my local environment but in production (given the volume I imagine) it doesn't seem to run well.

Comment: That query doesn't do the correct thing.  There is no join condition between table the delete is on.  So it will either delete everything, or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery in where clause take a lot of time 
you should use `with` and `using` this will be a lot a lot a lot ... faster

```
with 
    c_not_member as (
     -- here extarct the id of contacts that not in members
     SELECT 
        c.id
     FROM  contacts c LEFT JOIN  members m on c.id = m.contact_id
     WHERE  
        -- to get the contact that don't exist in member just
        -- use condition in a field on member that cannot be null
        -- in this case you have id
        m.id is null
        -- the only case when m.id is null is when c.id does not have m.contact_id maching c.id
        -- in another way c.id doesn't exists in m.contact_id 
                   )
DELETE FROM contacts all_c using c_not_member WHERE all_c.id = not_member.id ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tested this out and get similar results to the queries above. `Time: 249600.967 ms`.