# Is it possible to index on enum?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

The question is really about optimization of sql queries. Let us say we have the table so defined.

```sql
CREATE TYPE record_type AS ENUM (
  'TRANSFER',
  'TRADE',
  'VOUCHER'
);

CREATE TYPE record_status AS ENUM (
  'NEW',
  'VALIDATED',
  'EXPIRED'
);

CREATE TABLE good_records (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id uuid NOT NULL,
  type record_type NOT NULL,
  status record_status NOT NULL,
  amount numeric(36,18) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  expired_at timestamp WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  notification_sent boolean DEFAULT false,
);
```

I want to run an expiration check every 10 min, namely, I would run `SELECT * FROM good_records 
 where record_status = 'NEW' and notification_sent = false` (and `SELECT * FROM good_records where record_status = 'VALIDATED' and notification_sent = false`). But as I monitor the db resources usage, it comes with no surprise that that two queries costs a lot.

My question is whether it is possible to put indexing on the table somehow so that I can fasten the queries and save db resources.

I have briefly read the postgresql docs but with no good solution.

Comment: For performance optimization, always start with your version of Postgres. Also essential here: cardinalities for those enum values and rough characteristic of database activity. How many writes per time unit? And: Do you actually need `SELECT *`, or is a limited list of columns good enough? Any indexes there, yet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's certainly possible to index `enum` columns. But since there are typically only few distinct values, [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) are typically more efficient. Details depend on missing information.

For example, assuming there are only *few* rows with `notification_sent = false`, and all you need to retrieve is the `id`, this index would serve both queries:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON good_records (record_status, id)
WHERE notification_sent = false;
```

If there is a lot of write activity, be sure to have aggressive [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curent/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) settings [for the table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) to keep table and index bloat at bay and allow index-only scans.

Adding `id` to the index only makes sense if it can give you [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html).

If you never filter on `id`, use the `INCLUDE` clause instead (Postgres 11 or later). Slightly more efficient:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON good_records (record_status) INCLUDE (id)
WHERE notification_sent = false;
```

Related:

- [Optimize Postgres deletion of orphaned records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307730/optimize-postgres-deletion-of-orphaned-records/43405194#43405194)
- [Aggressive Autovacuum on PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21649/3684)
- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190158/3684)